# Xpath of Radio button is not working: Xpath is not clickable?

Tags: javascript, selenium, spring-boot, xpath, kotlin

I am trying to get the Xpath of the code but its showing not clickable.
I tried in chrome console and somehow make the xpath clickable but dont know how to use the xpath in selenium code.

In chrome console it work if you write like this

```
$x("//*[@id='no-voucher-id']")[0].click()
```

**Here is my code:**

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='no-voucher-id']")
 private lateinit var selectedNoVoucher: FluentList<FluentWebElement>

 selectedNoVoucher.click();
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div className="Voucher-container-section" >
  <div className="radio-item">
   <input type="radio" id="yes-voucher-id" name="voucher" value="Yes"/> 
   <label For="yes-voucher-id">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div className="radio-item">
   <input type="radio" id="no-voucher-id" name="voucher" value="No"/>
  <label htmlFor="no-voucher-id">No</label>
</div>
</div>

css
.radio-item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 6px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
  }

  .radio-item input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
  }

  .radio-item label {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  .radio-item label:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    border-radius: 11px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 10px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: #EE4823;
  }
```

**Error Message:**

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: Element [[ChromeDriver: chrome on Ubuntu] -> xpath: //input[@id='no-voucher-id']] is not clickable (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

I expect the output is the radio button should be clickable

Comment: which option is chosen?  Could be unclickable because it is already set?  You may want to post the actual browser's source here... seems like this is an approximation.

Comment: Check if there any iframe available?? if not then use `WebDriverWait` and below code. ```WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
   WebElement radioitem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("no-voucher-id")));
   radioitem.click();```

Answer (score 1):

If the element is in the view point then you can use this selector :

I would recommend you to use **ID** over **xpath** or any other locator :

for clicking on **Yes** radio button : `yes-voucher-id`

```
@FindBy(id="yes-voucher-id")
var selectedNoVoucher

selectedNoVoucher.click();
```

Just make sure that the ID should be unique.

You can replace the **id** for **No** button in similar way.